# Where is C# documentation using XML comments created (Visual Studio 2010)?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

Do you know where is this documentation created ?
Normally it can be created with :

```
/// <summary>
/// I just want to test something
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args"></param>
```

Do you know where are the options in VS that change it ?

Comment: Alternatively you could use Doxygen that also understands those XML comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setup for C# projects does not build the documentation, but it is easy to fix. Just:

1) Right click on the project that needs documentation and choose properties.
2) Click on the build tab on the left.
3) Check documentation box and choose path as appropriate.
4) Profit and enjoy.

Instructions are for VS 2010 premium, YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Building the XML documentation file from Visual Studio is only the beginning of the process.  The full process is as follows:

- Add XML comments to your project
- Have Visual Studio generate the XML doc file

  - Project properties
  - Build tab
  - XML documentation file
- Use a documentation generation tool to convert the XML file into a help file (chm), web site (html, aspx), or other formats.  Some tools to do this are:

  - [SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)
  - [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)

More information can be found in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/641364/28736).

Comment: Note that NDoc hasn't been updated in a while and might not do so well with recent .NET binaries. If using Sandcastle, consider using a tool to make it easier like http://shfb.codeplex.com/

Comment: Agreed.  My preference is Sandcastle with SHFB, but there are many options to choose from.